# "Native method not found" in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, unsatisfiedlinkerror

i have looked through all the other posts here about this subject but none of them helped me.

i am using a third party SDK (oovoo) and it contains a .jar file and .so file (armeabi-v7a)

as stated in allot of places, i put the .jar file in the libs folder and the armeabi-v7a folder (which contains the .so file) in a folder named jniLibs inside src/main

after building, when i unzip the .apk i see a folder named lib and inside it a folder named armeabi-v7a which contains the .so file

yet i still get this exception:

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.oovoo.core.ClientCore.VideoChannelPtr.nCreate:(Ljava/lang/String;)J
```

- why cant it reach the implementation?
- if it is in the lib folder in
  the .apk does it mean it will for it at runtime?

thanks allot!

android studio version 0.8.6
gradle version 1.12
oovoo version 1.2.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your questions specifically :

It can't reach the implementation because at runtime, when the java environment tries to load a native method named `java_com_oovoo_core_ClientCore_VideoChannelPtr_nCreate` with the prototype `int (string)` it doesn't find such a method loaded. This can be caused by the following :

- the `.so` library isn't loaded by the time you called that method , hence java doesn't know about it (so it's your mistake, you called the functions in wrong order)
- the `.so` library doesn't export such a function, which means you have no chance of fixing this
- the `.so` library loaded at runtime by the phone requires a different architecture besides `armv7s`. Be sure your device is `armv7s`.
- the folder in which the Android system is looking for native libs is different than you expect. I know this was an old issue, so create in your apk, in your lib folder both "armeabi-v7a" and "armeabi" , and copy that `.so` file in both

Regarding your 2nd question, yes, if you have the lib inside the apk you will have it at runtime.

Comment: thanks allot for your answer! i tried all the things you said, added a folder named armeabi and checked my device architecture. regarding your second thought  i dont think that is it because they have an example that runs on eclipse. regarding the most important thing i think, i tried loading the library with System.loadLibrary (in the same class, - where should o put that ? ) and it sais "Trying to load lib .." and after that "Added shared lib .." and then when it reaches the problematic code it crashes with "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=1)". please do you have any thoughts?

Comment: System.loadLibrary is the call you need, make sure to take out the "lib" prefix and the ".so" sufix .Sisgsegv means that in native code it accessed a "null pointer", so it's an issue with the library itself, or the way it's used. By your comment I take it you got past the linkage error (which is a step forward). Can you access any other native functions from the library without code crashing ? Regarding eclipse/other ide, it has nothing to do with the issues you are bumping into.

Comment: it is not crashing now! it turns out i needed to not call the library from the onCreate method. have no idea why... thanks allot!